# How to run docker and node together?

Tags: docker-compose, docusaurus

I want run docusaurus with docker which containing nginx and node.
My directories looking like this. Without docker docusaurus working correctly

```
application/
   blog/
   docs/
   src/
   static/
   babel.config.js
   default.conf
   docker-compose.yml
   docusaurus.config.js
   nginx.dockerfile
   nodejs.dockerfile
   package.json
   package-lock.json
   sidebars.js
```

In the default.conf I have

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Inside docker-compose.yml I have

```
version: '2'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nodejs.dockerfile
  container_name: nodejs
  ports:
    - "1602:3000"
   volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  networks:
    - application
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
  ports:
    - "1601:80"
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  depends_on:
    - nodejs
  networks:
    - application
networks:
  application:
    driver: bridge
```

Inside nginx.dockerfile I have

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Inside nodejs.dockerfile I have

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY ./ /var/www/html

RUN npm install
RUN npm start
EXPOSE 1602
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: What problem are you running into?  The one obvious thing I see is that you're trying to `RUN npm start`, starting the server during the image build, which isn't right; you probably want to make that line be the image's `CMD`.  You also have a bunch of unnecessary Compose options (`container_name:`, `volumes:`, `networks:`) that could be safely deleted.

Comment: in browser not opening. but docker-compose up not showing the error.